# Cloud Code, complex query with adding a key-value pair before response

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I want to get a batch of User objects using Cloud Code. And before collection of objects will send to client they have to take a unique number.
Now it's looking like this

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getUsers", function(request, response)
{
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    var mode = parseInt(request.params.mode);
    var username = request.params.username;
    var skip = parseInt(request.params.skip);
    var limit = parseInt(request.params.limit);

    if(mode==1)
    {
        query.notEqualTo("fbLogged",true)
        .descending("score")
        .notEqualTo("username",username)
        .skip(skip)
        .limit(limit);

        query.find({
            success: function(objects)
            {
                var i = 0;
                objects.forEach(function(item)
                {
                    item["rank"]=skip+i; //setting a unique number (position based on score)
                });

                response.success(objects);
            },
            error: function(error)
            {
                response.error(error);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And how I use it on client side...

```
void Start () {
    IDictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    dict.Add("username", "477698883");
    dict.Add("skip", "300");
    dict.Add("limit", "50");
    dict.Add("mode", "1");
    ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<IEnumerable<object>>("getUsers", dict).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if(t.IsCanceled || t.IsFaulted)
        {
            foreach (var e in t.Exception.InnerExceptions)
                Debug.LogError(e.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            var r = t.Result;
            List<ParseUser> users = new List<ParseUser>();
            foreach(var o in r)
            {
                try {
                    ParseObject pu = (ParseObject)o;

                    foreach (var key in pu.Keys)
                        Debug.Log(key + " = " + pu[key]);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.LogError(e.Message);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

As you see I just display first of received objects.
And it gives me this data.
[image]

But where is the "rank" field?

Answer (score 0):

I just found solution. Each ParseObject which will send to Client by response.success() have to be saved on Parse before sent.
Now my code looks like this and it works

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getUsers", function(request, response)
{
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    var mode = parseInt(request.params.mode);
    var username = request.params.username;
    var skip = parseInt(request.params.skip);
    var limit = parseInt(request.params.limit);

    if(mode==1)
    {
        query.notEqualTo("fbLogged",true)
        .descending("score")
        .notEqualTo("username",username)
        .skip(skip)
        .limit(limit);

        query.find({
            success: function(objects)
            {
                for(var i = 0; i<objects.length; i++)
                {
                    objects[i].set("rank", skip+i);
                    objects[i].save();
                }

                response.success(objects);
            },
            error: function(error)
            {
                response.error(error);
            }
        });
    }
});
```